# Reference of the 1st derivation of elastic relativistic collision in one dimension

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, collision, history, specific-reference

I am researching in the relativistic collisions. Do you know what is the first paper or book derived the final velocities in terms of initial velocities in one dimension? I found the derivation on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Relativistic_derivation_using_hyperbolic_functions
But without mentioning any reference.

Comment: Are you asking who was the first person to derive this expression? Because this appears in just about every book in relativity.

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Drjh 
Yes, exactly. I mean the complicated fraction expression of final velocities in terms of rest masses and initial velocities

Comment: @AhmedKamalKassem, are you sure you want the first derivation? It could be in some strange notation, e.g. using quaternions for 3d  vectors, and imaginary time to make space-time scalar product look like the Eucledian product. Could also contain partially erroneous statements, which have since then been fixed by generations of later authors. Even if you find it and understand it, you will have to re-understand it again, later, in modern notation. By the way, the complicated function you have mentioned, would probably look much simpler in modern 4-vector notation (just a guess).

Comment: @Cryo 
I agree totally with you. My problem is only if I used this formula (For example Wikipedia formula) in any research, Shouldn't I put the first paper that derived this formula. I think the Wikipedia formula is correct if we are not taking Quantum Mechanics into consideration. Or even if it is wrong what is the reference of first relativistic (non-quantum) formula?

Comment: @AhmedKamalKassem, no, you don't need to put the original author. This is now textbook stuff, so reference text-book. Jackson, "Classical electrodynamics" has a good section on SR. Barut's "Electrodynamics and Classical Theory of Fields and Particles" is also good. Then, of course, there is Misner-Thorne-Wheeler. I am sure people here can name more

Comment: @AhmedKamalKassem, I do understand your problem now though. It is difficult to know which are good textbooks in a field that you have not worked in. I usually pick up such candidates by checking what other people reference in papers, but it does not always work :-)

Comment: Could you track down the author of that Wikipedia section, from its history of edits? Then you could ask that author for a reference, hopefully to be included in the Wikipedia article. - Is it the formula involving the function Z and the exponential functions (which isn’t a standard textbook form)?

Answer (score 1):

The 13:29, 13 December 2012 version  by Zdmitruk
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Elastic_collision&direction=next&oldid=526103870
introduced this derivation with the exponential function and with $Z$ (the reciprocal of the product of time-dilation factors). However, there doesn't seem to be a user with that name on Wikipedia.

The strategy in the section entitled "Another derivation relativistic formulas for the collision"
(later renamed to "Relativistic derivation using hyperbolic functions" )
writes conservation of total 4-momentum in terms of rapidities $\theta_i=\mbox{arctanh}(v_i/c)$,
and then in terms of $\exp\theta_i$ (Doppler factors, Bondi k-factors, eigenvalues of the boost, which are associated with light-cone coordinates).

A similar approach is carried out in

- Lapidus, I.R., "A useful notation for relativistic kinematics"
  Am. J. Phys. 54, 750 (1986); http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.14472
  although he does not express the result in terms of the final spatial velocities
  and it seems he only considers this an algebraic technique, even though he has written the Doppler formula. There is no mention of Bondi, eigenvalues, light-cone coordinates, etc...